# Initializing stream in constructor

Tags: c++

I'm just starting to learn C++ having come from a C# background.

I am creating a class that will parse CSV data, and I want the class to be initialized with either a filepath or a stream. If a filepath is passed the `_str_in` should be set to a newly opened `ifstream`.

My code below compiles but gives a warning on the second constructor "reference member is initialized to a temporary that doesn't persist after the constructor exits".
I am guessing the warning relates to the following:

1. `ifstream` is created and `_str_in` is set to reference it
2. the memory assigned to `ifstream` is released after the constructor exits
3. `_str_in` now points to non-allocated memory and could become corrupted.

I've tried different ways of accomplishing this and checked many SO questions but I'm stumped — any suggestions?

```
class TokenParser
{
    std::istream& _str_in;
    char _delim;

public:
    TokenParser::TokenParser(std::istream& str_in, char delim) : _str_in(str_in), _delim(delim)
    {
    }

    TokenParser::TokenParser(std::string& file_path, char delim) : _str_in(std::ifstream(file_path)), _delim(delim)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is pretty much what the compiler describes: the object created by `std::ifstream(file_path)` will be gone by the time the constructor completes, so the reference `_str_in` would instantly become dangling.

You could work around this problem by making an `std::ifstream` object inside `TokenParser`, and using it when the second constructor is called:

```
class TokenParser
{
    std::ifstream _file;
    std::istream& _str_in;
    char _delim;

public:
    TokenParser::TokenParser(std::istream& str_in, char delim) : _str_in(str_in), _delim(delim)
    {
    }

    TokenParser::TokenParser(std::string& file_path, char delim) : _file(file_path), _str_in(_file)), _delim(delim)
    {
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
Using *universal reference* and `std::move` in `<algorithm>`

```
class TokenParser
{
std::istream&& _str_in; // notice the && 'universal reference'
char _delim;

public:
TokenParser::TokenParser(std::istream&& str_in, char delim) 
: _str_in(std::move(str_in)), _delim(delim)
{}
// other ctors...
}
```